# Split a array in VBA and output to multiple columns in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a long array that exceeds the maximum number of rows of a single column (1048576), and I wish to output this array into multiple columns, for example, if my array length is 3145728, and so I intend to create 3 separate arrays, each with length 1048576, so 1 to 1048576 would be output to column A, 1048577 to 2097152 to column B, and 2097153 to 3145728 to column C. My code attempted is as follows:

```
Sub test()

'for simplicity, just created a simply long array
Dim arrIn(1 To 3145728, 1 To 1) As Long
For i = 1 To 3145728
    arrIn(i, 1) = i
Next i

'created 3 separate arrays, each with length of 1048576
Dim arrOut1(1 To 1048576, 1 To 1) As Long, arrOut2(1 To 1048576, 1 To 1) As Long, arrOut3(1 To 1048576, 1 To 1) As Long
Dim p As Long, p2 As Long, p3 As Long

'because counter p is going to be from 1 to 3145728, for the second and third arrays, the counter need to restart from 1 and upto 1048576
p2 = 1
p3 = 1

For p = 1 To 3145728

    Select Case p

        Case Is <= 1048576
            arrOut1(p, 1) = arrIn(p, 1)

        Case Is <= 2097152
            arrOut2(p2, 1) = arrIn(p, 1)
            p2 = p2 + 1

        Case Is <= 3145728
            arrOut3(p3, 1) = arrIn(p, 1)
            p3 = p3 + 1

    End Select

Next p

Range("A1:A1048576") = arrOut1
Range("B1048577: B2097152") = arrOut2
Range("C2097153:C3145728") = arrOut3

End Sub
```

The first column (arrOut1) was output to column A, however, when it comes to the second column (arrOut2), VBA returns Run-time error '1004': Menthod 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

I checked the locals windows results, p2 and p3 were 1048577, and arrOut2(1,1) = 1048577, arrOut2(1,1) = 1048578, and so on, seems the arrays all get populated, however I'm not sure what is prohibiting them from being spitted out to the columns. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If No of maximum rows is 1048576. how using `Range("B1048577: B2097152")` and so on.  Simply make it `Range("A1:A1048576") = arrOut1` `Range("B1:B1048576") = arrOut2` `Range("C1:C1048576") = arrOut3`

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I think my mind was trapped and so confused myself so much. Thank you for pointing out! I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, just realized that Range(“B1048577:B...) was nonsense... so it is solved. Thank you!